# How to use i18n routes in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization

How to use a i18n implementation in Symfony2 with the following routes:

**/login** (en_US)

**/entrar** (pt_BR)

**/logout** (en_US)

**/sair** (pt_BR)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Isn't that what you're looking for?

edit: +github link: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle